# Change JS file encoding to UTF-8 with signature using Grunt

Tags: javascript, encoding, windows-8, utf-8, gruntjs

I am working on a build script for Win8 JS apps and looking for a way to automate encoding files as UTF-8 with signature so the compiled project will pass WACK test. I noticed the following option in the Grunt documentation:

`grunt.file.defaultEncoding = 'utf8';`

but wasn't sure what to actually set the encoding to. Any suggestions?

In Visual Studio you would simply open the file, click save as, and select UTF-8 with signature which is second from the top. This is time consuming if your app has lots of JS files, especially ones that are generated during build process

Answer (score 2):

As of Grunt version 0.4.2 you can now perserve the BOM when writing files:

`grunt.file.preserveBOM = true;`

There are other Windows improvements as well. [It has been added to the documentation as well.](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.file)

I found a [bug](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/issues/806) that explained the same problem that you have, and the [changelog](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/blob/v0.4.2/CHANGELOG) says that it should be fixed now.

Comment: I don't know why ,but in 0.4.5 it's still not preserving the BOM, despite me setting the grunt.file.preserveBOM to true. The only real solution for me is the one from @planky.

Answer (score 2):

There is a grunt task now that can add BOM to your files: grunt-byte-order-mark. I just used it and my app now passes the Windows App Certification Kit tests.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-byte-order-mark

Comment: as @belzebu noted in Allan's comment, the preserveBOM doesn't seem to work in 0.4.5 but the grunt-byte-order-mark task does seem to do it

Comment: It may be that your original files didn't have the BOM or that another task was stripping them off, not grunt itself. If that is the case, grunt-byte-order-mark will add them whether they were there before or not.